# jsFiddle for other languages?

Tags: web-services, jsfiddle

it would be great... like one for python? PHP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I like http://ideone.com/ - it can compile or interpret many languages.

For older languages, http://repl.it/languages is invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

you can try http://kodingen.com

Comment: not at all working for me -> lots of bugs but thanks

Answer (score 1):

JS Fiddle for PHP:
PHP Assist
http://phpassist.com/

Answer (score 0):

[TryF#](http://tryfsharporg.cloudapp.net/Tutorials.aspx#) has a Silverlight-based in-browser F# compiler. It is used for their tutorial, but you can also run arbitrary code in there.

I'm also sure I've seen a site which will run snippets in any .Net language - but they do it on the server. Can't find a link for it now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://pythonfiddle.com/, which is pretty nice for Python.

Answer (score 0):

[dotnetfiddle.net](http://dotnetfiddle.net)
For c#,vb and f#

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://codeenv.com/ you can have a fiddle in any language you like.

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.